# Can't write CSV file using CHCSVParser (CHCSVWriter)

Tags: objective-c, csv, export

I want to export data from my application into a csv file.

I found CHCSVParser by [Dave Delong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong)

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

I created a test project, imported CHCSVWriter and wrote this:

```
CHCSVWriter * csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:@"~/testfile.csv" atomic:NO];
    [csvWriter writeField:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"One"]];
    [csvWriter writeLine];
    [csvWriter writeField:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Two"]];
    [csvWriter writeLine];
    [csvWriter closeFile];
    [csvWriter release];
```

But I get no testfile.csv in the Finder :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to expand the `~` for this to work. You can either update the parser to handle the `~` for you or you can initialize the parser like this,

```
NSString * filePath = @"~/testfile.csv";
filePath = [filePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

CHCSVWriter * csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:filePath atomic:NO];
```